# adding scheduled task programmatically

Tags: shell, scheduled-tasks

I need to add scheduled task programmatically, trought php script on win 8.1.
I'm developing an app on my local system, which is windows, so I can't use crons.
Now, my questions are can scheduled task be applied on unix web server and how to add it trought php script?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. **Linux** and **BSD** servers have `crons`. **Windows** servers have `scheduled tasks`.

They are utilities from the ***OS***, so you **can't** create those through PHP, *unless* you use the exec() function to run terminal command to create that task.

I would recommend you to simply create the task via `ssh`

Good luck!

**EDIT**

If i am not wrong, the command to create *crons* on *NIX is `crontab`

Comment: Windows have scheduled tasks. I recommend you using a _virtual desktop_ inside your windows with the *nix you're going to use on the webserver